# integrate product of two gaussian pdfs where one marginal is not gaussian

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

I'm seeing some help as of how to integrate the product of two Gaussian PDFs analytically, $g(y_n | x_n)$ and $f(x_n | x_{n-1})$ as described by Whiteley (http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~manpw/apf_chapter.pdf). 
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y_n | x_n)f(x_n | x_{n-1})dx_n
\end{equation}
It's well known that the product of two Gaussians $f(x)g(x)$ is a new unscaled Gaussian, however for my case the conditional probability $g(y_n | x_n)$ is Gaussian but the marginal $g(y_n)$ itself may not be Gaussian. That is, we have two time series defined by means $bx_n, ax_{n-1}$ and variances $\sigma_f^2, \sigma_g^2$ respectively (where $\epsilon$ represents white noise):
\begin{align}
x_n &= ax_{n-1} + \sigma_f\epsilon_f \\
y_n &= bx_n + \sigma_g\epsilon_g
\end{align}
and I want to integrate the product of the two corresponding PDFs
\begin{align}
g(y_n | x_n) &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_g}exp\big(-\frac{(y_n-bx_n)^2}{2\sigma_g^2} \big) \\
f(x_n | x_{n-1} ) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_f}\big(-\frac{(x_n-ax_{n-1})^2}{2\sigma_f^2} \big) 
\end{align}
The derivation for the general case is outlined step by step (http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf), however for my case the details get a bit tricker. Taking the product of f and g:
\begin{equation}
f(x)g(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_f\sigma_g}exp\Big(-\frac{(y_n-bx_n)^2}{2\sigma_f^2} + \frac{(x_n-ax_{n-1})^2}{2\sigma_g^2} \Big)
\end{equation}
Expand the two quadratic terms in the exponents and collect terms:
\begin{align}
Let \beta :&= \Big(-\frac{(y_n-bx_n)^2}{2\sigma_f^2} + \frac{(x_n-ax_{n-1})^2}{2\sigma_g^2} \Big) \\
&= \frac{y_n^2\sigma_g^2 - 2by_nx_n\sigma_g^2 + b^2x_n\sigma_g^2 + x_n^2\sigma_f^2 - 2ax_nx_{n-1}\sigma_f^2 + a^2x_{n-1}^2\sigma_f^2}{2\sigma_f^2\sigma_g^2} \\
&= \frac{y_n^2\sigma_g^2 + x_n^2\sigma_f^2 - 2x_n(by_n\sigma_g^2 - ax_{n-1}\sigma_f^2) + b^2x_n\sigma_g^2   + a^2x_{n-1}^2\sigma_f^2}{2\sigma_f^2\sigma_g^2}
\end{align}
Is there is a neat way to make this work out nicely to get a closed form solution for the mean, variance and scaling factor of the new Gaussian? Any help would be appreciated!